# First control display freeze UI in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Edit**
`I changed the title because I found the real cause of the freeze. The cause is in my awnser`

In WPF, the first time you display a control, it can be slow because the XAML will be parsed. Next time the control is displayed, it will be instantanous because the XAML is already parsed.

I tried to reduce the UI freeze by using a defered visual loading system which make visual collapsed and make them visible in a low priority dispatcher call. This work very will with ItemsControl with a lot of items but it still doesn't solve the first parsing UI freeze.

Is there a good way to reduce the freeze caused by XAML parsing?

I was thinking about parsing all the XAML at app startup. It would slowdown the startup but the application will be without freeze after this. 
The difficulty is how to get all the BALM files (compiled XAML) and how to store the result in the same place where WPF look for them.

Comment: But XAML files are compiled into BAML when you compile your application. I'd explore further the fact that you need to defer UI loading because it's too complex, maybe it's the root cause you should solve.

Comment: If you are using a recent version of Visual Studio, I would encourage you to use the Performance Profiler tool to ensure that you are having the performance bottleneck you think you are. In VS2017, it can be found under Debug > Performance Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. the slow down did not came from XAML parsing. it came from some static contructor who was loading some dll. Thats why it was slow only the first time. I moved the static initialisation to a thread.